# python if statement evaluation with multiple values

Tags: python

I'm not exactly sure why but when I execute this section of code nothing happens.

```
while (True) :

    choice = str(input("Do you want to draw a spirograph? (Y/N) "))

    if choice == 'n' or 'N' :
        break

    elif choice == 'y' or 'Y' :    

       <CODE>

    else :
        print("Please enter a valid command.")
        choice = input("Do you want to draw a spirograph? (Y/N)")
```

Comment: Edit your code section and add `while` line to it. I don't do this myself cause your problem may rely on it.

Comment: So many SO questions would be avoided in Python self-linted this case..

Comment: FWIW, you don't need parenthesis around your predicate. `while True:` is better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Comment: (And see the many linked answers on the duplicate such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-name-kevin-or-jon-or-inbar-always-evaluate-to-true?lq=1)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It won't work because the `'N'` literal always evaluates to `True` within your `if` statement.

Your `if` condition currently stands as `if choice == 'n' or 'N' :`, which is equivalent to `if (choice == 'n') or ('N')`, which will always evaluate to `True` irrespective of the value of variable `choice`, since the literal `'N'` always evaluates to `True`.

Instead, use one of the following

- `if choice == 'n' or choice == 'N' :`
- `if choice in 'nN' :`
- `if choice in ('n', 'N') :`

The same holds for your `elif` block as well. You can read more about [Truth Value testing here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

Answer (score 5):

This expression doesn't do what you want:

```
choice == 'n' or 'N'
```

It is interpretted as this:

```
(choice == 'n') or 'N'
```

You might want to try this instead:

```
choice in 'nN'
```