# Python if elif not getting expected results

Tags: python, if-statement, numbers

In Python 3. It reads correctly the 1st and the 2nd variable when they have the highest value. But the 3rd is not.

```
n1 = int(input("1st Number:\n"))
n2 = int(input("2nd Number:\n"))
n3 = int(input("3rd Number:\n"))

if n1 > n2 and n3:
    print(f'\033[1;31m{n1}\033[m')
elif n2 > n1 and n3:
    print(f'\033[4;32m{n2}\033[m')
elif n3 > n1 and n2:
    print(f'\033[33m{n3}\033[m') #When is the highest value it's not considered.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python if statement evaluation with multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228747/python-if-statement-evaluation-with-multiple-values)

Comment: `if n1 > n2 and n1 > n3:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the condition `n1 > n2` will be `True` if `n1` is greater than `n2`, and the condition `n3` **will always be True because n3 is an integer**. As *all non-zero integers* are considered `True` in a boolean context, the same logic applies for the second `elif` i.e `n2 > n1`. So you need to change the condition like this.

```
n1 = int(input("1st Number:\n"))
n2 = int(input("2nd Number:\n"))
n3 = int(input("3rd Number:\n"))

if n1 > n2 and n1 > n3:
    print(f'\033[1;31m{n1}\033[m')
elif n2 > n1 and n2 > n3:
    print(f'\033[4;32m{n2}\033[m')
elif n3 > n1 and n3 > n2:
    print(f'\033[33m{n3}\033[m') #When is the highest value it's not considered.
```

Comment: All *nonzero integers* are considered true in a boolean context