# If I add OR options to IF, the code doesn't run properly

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

When I put in line 7 `or` the code doesn't work as intended.
Can someone please tell me the reason for that?

```
# x = int(input("Insert price for your product :"))
x=100
print ("Does your product include taxes?")
# answer = input(" yes or no ")
answer = "no"
if answer == "yes" or "Yes" or "YES":
    print ("final price is : ", x, "\n the tax is :" ,x*0.17)
elif answer == "no":
     print ("final price is : ", x*1.17, "\n the taxes is ", x*0.17)
else:
    print ("Your answer is not according to the dictionnary - try again")
```

I expect that any input for the word YES will work for the `if` in the code.

Comment: "The code is destroyed" ???

Comment: Proofread your question and improve it. It is barely intelligible. (Also proofread your code.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python if statement evaluation with multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228747/python-if-statement-evaluation-with-multiple-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using `if answer == "yes" or "Yes" or "YES":`. you should try

`if answer == "yes" or answer == "Yes" or answer == "YES":`.

OR use python built-in method called `lower()`, so that you can lowercase your input

```
x = int(input("Insert price for your product :"))

print ("Does your product include taxes?")
answer = input(" yes or no ").lower()
if answer == "yes":
    print ("finel price is : ", x, "\nthe tax is :" ,x*0.17)
elif answer == "no":
     print ("finel price is : ", x*1.17, "\nthe taxes is ", x*0.17)
else:
    print ("Your answer is not according to the dictionary - try agin")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if answer in ["yes","Yes","YES"]:
            OR
if answer == "yes" or answer=="Yes" or answer=="YES":
```

Instead of.

```
if answer == "yes" or "Yes" or "YES":
```

Answer (score -1):

It's an issue with syntax.

```
if answer == "yes" or "Yes" or "YES":
```

In this context in Python you need to spell out each time what variable you are using, for example:

```
if answer == "yes" or answer== "Yes" or answer== "YES":
```

or you can format it a different way such as:

```
answer = answer.lower()
if answer == "yes":
    print ("final price is : ", x, "\nthe tax is : " , x*0.17)
elif answer == "no":
    print ("final price is : ", x*1.17, "\nthe tax is : ", x*0.17)
else:
    print ("Your answer is not according to the dictionary - try again")
```

this solution will change `answer` to be all lowercase which allows people to also write things such as YeS or yeS. This also keeps the code from looking cluttered.